# mysql workbench SSL connection error: SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths failed

Tags: mysql-workbench

Trying to setup ssl connection to my server every file path seems to be right

but keeping get error SSL connection error: SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths failed what this may be?

[image]

Comment: Did you ever discover a solution?  I have a co-worker with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and was able to fix the issue by changing my pem files to utf-8 encoding and that resolved the problem.